# How to include SAMl assertion in soap security header

Tags: c++, soap, saml, saml-2.0, gsoap

I am using gsoap 2.8.0.  In one of the request, I need to add token got from Vmware SSO Server using SAML Assertion.

When I generate code using gsoap (wsdl2h and soapcpp2), I am getting error: 
.\wsdlout\vimService.h(224691): *WARNING*: struct _saml__Assertion declared in wsse.h:197 has no content

In the generated code, I am not able to find "struct _saml__Assertion" definition.

How to add SAML assertion in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Recommend to upgrade your gsoap installation to 2.8.40, because the type is actually `struct saml1__AssertionType` or `struct saml2__AssertionType` depending on the SAML version you want.

The saml assertion is declared in the gsoap root dir under import/saml1.h (SAML 1.0) and import/saml2.h (SAML 2.0). The wsse.h file has one or both of these:

```
#import "saml1.h"
#import "saml2.h"
```

These suffice to define the SAML assertion structures. Make sure the use `soapcpp2 -Igsoap-2.8/gsoap/import` to let soapcpp2 locate the correct .h files in the import dir under the root gsoap dir.

See all of these details on [WS-Trust and SAML](https://www.genivia.com/doc/wst/html/index.html) in the updated soap documentation.